# How to edit a footer in joomla: using media manager image folder?

Tags: joomla, media, footer

I am trying to include a footer on a joomla website and need to reference an image. Ideally it would be editable by the client.

At the moment I have a template which has an index.php file, but if I reference the img src to be in the images folder, it does not reference the template images, but the media manager folder.

What is the best way to approach this please, for maintinability and also to be safe from updates and overwriting them.

Comment: will the client have access to Back-End?

Comment: At least the admin area. Probably the code, but ideally a solution on just having the admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new "CUSTOM HTML" module and place following code in it. You can even use editor to modify it and upload new pics. I recommend using [JCE editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88), makes things much simpler.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   <img src="/path/to/your/images.jpg" />
</div>
```

So you need to do the following:

1. Login to Back-End
2. Go to Extensions->Module Manager
3. Click "New" button
4. Click on "Custom HTML"
5. Configure you module the way you like it. Set "Show Title" to "NO". Make sure you position it in the right spot, most likely you need to use "footer" or "bottom"... this depends on template.